# Is it possible to create a cross platform app using phonegap to sync files between different devices?

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, cordova

I am trying to build a cross mobile platform app to sync files and photos between devices, something like dropbox but for mobile or like [`sugarsync`](https://www.sugarsync.com/videos/?v_setup).

I want it to run on iphone/ipad , android, windows phone.

So for example the user can put a file on his iphone and can see it on his windows phone automatically.

Is that possible using phonegap apis or should i search for another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You retrieve the file from the local device and upload to your server.
You can then download the file from the server on the other device.

You can do this using the [`FileTransfer`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) functionality in PhoneGap (supported on Android, iOS, BlackBerry & WP7) without the need to write any plugins or native code.

You'd just have to write the permissions side of things, the ability to return a list of files stored on the server and manage the syncing of changes.

**BEWARE: There a legal, privacy and security issues with accessing and storing other peoples files.**

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean P2P or using a server?

In both cases I guess your best chance is using Sockets.

http://remysharp.com/2010/10/04/websockets-in-phonegap-projects/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to natively write a Sync service for each platform, and then expose that Sync service via a `PhoneGap` plugin. PhoneGap is still the way to go due to its cross platform support